# Page not found (404) Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, django-urls

So hello guys i have run into trouble while running my project.

[image]

this is my urls.py

```
 from unicodedata import name
 from django.urls import path
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import re_path
 from . import views
 app_name = "Project"

 urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index , name='index'),
     path('counter', views.counter, name='counter'),
     path('Register', views.Register, name= 'Register'),
     path('login', views.login, name='login'),
     path('logout', views.logout, name = 'logout'),
     path('post/<str:pk>', views.post, name = 'post'),
     path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
     re_path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0-100]+)', views.viewAppointment, 
     name='appointment'),
     re_path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0-100]+)/AddDiagnonsis', 
     views.addDiagnosis, name='AddDiagnosis')
     ]
```

and this my views.py

```
def viewAppointment(request, appointment_id):
    appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(id=appointment_id)

    return render(request, 'appointment_form.html', {'Appointment': appointment})
```

i dont know what do im new here at django

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a URL referenced as `appointment`, only `appointment/appointment=...` and `appointment/appointment=.../AddDiagnonsis` (which you probably misspelled btw)

If you tried going to this url by writing it, you wrote it wrong or forgot to put an url `appointment` in your urlpatterns.

Comment: what do i have to change ?

Comment: By looking at your code, you need to go to a url you defined, so for example ```htpp://127.0.0.1/appointment/appointment=id``` (with 'id' the id of one of your appointment instances)

You could also add ```appointment``` to your urls with this code :
```path('appointment', views.appointment, name='appointment)``` however that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for since it would require you to create a new view and wouldn't link to any appointment instance